# On tap the windows button ,which event executed successfully which tells the app is going to background

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I am new in windows phone app and working on `signalR` in app.

I have `HubConnection` and have a `disconnect` function, which i want to execute when app is going to background.

I am calling this `disconnect` function in `Deactivated` event of `App.xaml.cs`, this function is called successfully but completed at the time when i resume again my app.

Please help if anyone knows how to fully execute a function before the app going to `Dormant` state? Or is there any other event which runs after tapping on `Window Button`?

Comment: Does it take a long time (more than 10 seconds) for the `disconnect` function to complete? and is this function synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: thnx to reply kennyzx,this is synchronous functon ,this function is not completing on deactivated event , after resuming app again this function executing successfully, but i want to complete it before tha app going to its dormant state

Comment: and how much time it takes to run to completion?

Comment: 3 or 5 seconds after calling .. if we call it by click of any other button during running app